# Using a method while looping through an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby-aaws to return Amazon Products and I want to enter them into my DB. I have created a model Amazonproduct and I have created a method get_amazon_data to return an array with all the product information. When i define the specific element in the array ( e.g. to_a[0] ) and then use ruby-aaws item_attributes method, it returns the name I am searching for and saves it to my DB. I am trying to iterate through the array and still have the item_attributes method work. When i don't define the element, i get this error: undefined method `item_attributes' for #Array:0x7f012cae2d68

Here is the code in my controller.

```
def create
@arr = Amazonproduct.get_amazon_data( :r ).to_a
 @arr.each { |name|
   @amazonproduct = Amazonproduct.new(params[:amazonproducts])
   @amazonproduct.name = @arr.item_attributes.title.to_s
 }
```

EDIT: Code in my model to see if that helps:

```
class Amazonproduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.get_amazon_data(r)
   resp = Amazon::AWS.item_search('GourmetFood', { 'Keywords' => 'Coffee Maker' })
   items = resp.item_search_response.items.item
   end
end
```

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what your classes are doing but to use #each, you can do something like

```
hash = {}

[['name', 'Macbook'], ['price', 1000]].each do |sub_array|
  hash[sub_array[0]] = sub_array[1]
end
```

which gives you a hash like

```
{ 'name' => 'Macbook', 'price' => 1000 }
```

This hash may be easier to work with

```
@product = Product.new
@product.name = hash[:name]
....
```

### EDIT

Try

```
def create
  @arr = Amazonproduct.get_amazon_data( :r ).to_a
  @arr.each do |aws_object|
    @amazonproduct = Amazonproduct.new(params[:amazonproducts])
    @amazonproduct.name = aws_object.item_attributes.title.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm, I added my Model code to see if that makes it helps. I don't understand exactly how to work with the hash here. The trouble that I am having is using method against an element in the Array, not against the Array itself. This method: .item_attributes.title.to_s needs to act on a specific record in the Array ( like [0] or [1], e.t.c.) and will not work on the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Amazon API, but I do observe that `@arr` is an array. Arrays do not usually have methods like `item_attributes`, so you probably lost track of which object was which somewhere in the coding process. It happens ;)

Try moving that `.item_attributes` call onto the object that supports that method. Maybe `amazonproduct.get_amazon_data(:r)`, before its being turned into an array with `to_a`, has that method?

Comment: I tried that in the console, but the method .itemattributes I think only works on specific elements in the array. For example, Amazonproducts.get_amazon_data( :r ).to_a[0].item_attributes.title.to_s will return the title of the first element in the Array. Thanks!